# Выбор объекта в PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Требуется организовать выбор угольного бассейна из выпадающего списка. Для этого к свойству прикреплён атрибут TypeConverter(typeof(CoalFieldConverter)). Угольный бассейн является не строкой, а объектом класса CoalField. Но почему-то внутренний механизм .NET пихает в ComboBox Items не сами объекты, а результат работы метода ToString. Поэтому при выборе элемента возникает ошибка: "Невозможно привести тип String к типу CoalField". Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в выпадающем списке содержались не строки, а объекты?

```
    [DisplayName(@"Бассейн")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CoalFieldConverter))]
    public CoalField Field { get; set; }

class CoalFieldConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private List<CoalField> _coalFields;
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(
      ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(
      ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
      ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        _coalFields = new List<CoalField>();
        // Тут заполняю коллекцию 
        return new StandardValuesCollection(_coalFields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен `TypeConverter`, а не `IValueConverter`? Думаю, то, что `TypeConverter` есть, это так, не имеющая отношения к делу деталь. Но это для WPF, как правильно делать в WinForms я не знаю.

Comment: @VladD, IValueConverter здесь точно не при чём. Насколько мне известно, он позволяет преобразовывать значения при динамической привязке (Binding). Например, DependencyProperty имеет логический тип, а в элементе управления отображается текст да/нет. 

А приведённый код взят из [этой статьи][1]. Разница лишь в том, что ComboBox.Items должен содержать не строки, а объекты класса CoalField.

  [1]: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml#EIIAC

Comment: Сделал костыль в виде поиска нужного объекта в списке _coalFields по имени.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае стоит использовать `ObservableCollection`. ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private CoalField _selectedCoalField;
  private ObservableCollection<CoalField> _coalFields;

  public MyViewModel()
  {
    CoalFields = new ObservableCollection<CoalField>
    {
      new CoalField(),
      new CoalField(),
    };
  }

  public ObservableCollection<CoalField> CoalFields
  {
    get { return _coalFields; }
    set
    {
      if (Equals(value, _coalFields))
      {
        return;
      }
      _coalFields = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public CoalField SelectedCoalField
  {
    get { return _selectedCoalField; }
    set
    {
      if (Equals(value, _selectedCoalField))
      {
        return;
      }
      _selectedCoalField = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CoalFields}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoalField}"/>
```

Comment: @Veikedo, вы невнимательно читаете вопрос. Во-первых, ComboBox нужен внутри PropertyGrid. Во-вторых, откуда вы выкопали WPF? Используется обычное приложение Windows Forms.